# ffmpeg makes yellow patches in gifs

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, gif

I have a bunch of png images made from a python script. When I convert the images to a mp4 format using ffmpeg, the video looks good. But the moment I make them into gifs it starts creating random yellow patches as shown below.
[image]

The syntax I use to convert png to gif is `ffmpeg -i img%04d.png animation.gif`

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you have tagged as **ImageMagick**? Anyway, try making the GIF with ImageMagick `convert img*png -delay 80 animation.gif`

Comment: GIF does not support partial transparency. So that could cause your issue.

Comment: Provide one of the PNG input files.

Comment: @fmw42 transparency was the issue. I was able to avoid the yellow patches by disabling transparency in the fig window. Mind rewriting your comment as an answer so that I can give it green tick ?? (just copy-paste will do) Thanks.

Comment: That is ok. The answer is too short to really qualify. But thanks anyway.

Comment: If it helps, I had the same problem, tried wih ImageMagick as suggested by @MarkSetchell and it worked great